# Poisson distribution with glmer - pairwise comparisons

Tags: t-test, poisson-distribution, paired-comparisons, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I am analyzing counting data from a field experiment using the `glmer` procedure according to a Poisson distribution. The model works and I can visualize the results using the normal code `summary(model)` .

I would like to obtain pairwise comparisons (like a t-test) amoung my factors (as instance, to have an output similar to the one that I can obtain with the function `lsmeans` for a linear model)

How can I obtain something like this?

Comment: FYI, `lsmeans` (in the **lsmeans** package) does work for `glmer` objects. By default, the results are on the linear predictor scale, but you can get them on the original response scale by adding `type = "response"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the **multcomp** package, which can test general linear hypotheses, including pair-wise comparisons for objects of class `mer` as produced by `glmer()`.

An example walk-through blog post is [Multiple Comparisons for GLMMs using glmer() & glht()](http://thebiobucket.blogspot.ca/2011/06/glmm-with-custom-multiple-comparisons.html).

More details about the package are available in the package Vignettes on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/index.html), in patricular see the Vignette [Simultaneous Inference in General Parametric Models](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/vignettes/generalsiminf.pdf)